# How to intercept and extract content of receiving popup

Tags: android, popupwindow, intercept

So, I programmable make ussd call, which results in receiving popup windows with some text.

How to intercept and extract content of this popup window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no means for you to "intercept and extract content of this popup window", as one app cannot "intercept and extract content" from the UI of any other app written by somebody else.

One exception would be if your app is running with superuser privileges on a rooted device, where you could take a screenshot and attempt to use OCR or something to "extract content of this popup window".

Comment: Thank you for  your answer. I thought it is possible to get,for example,some needed number from that popup,by parsing text,like i could get one from received SMS message. Or could I?

Comment: @user3367939: If it is a popup window, there is no way for you to access its contents. An SMS message does not appear in a popup window -- you get that information via a `BroadcastReceiver`.